# Installed Xubuntu but see no WiFi option in NetworkManager

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, network-manager, iphone

Just successfully installed Xubuntu 16.04 (well, almost successfully), as I now seem to have no option to enable any WiFi - the option is simply not there in NetworkManager.

Totally new to Llinux/Xubuntu, but happy to use terminal if advised.

There are loads of answers here on that issue, not sure which one would apply to my spacific issue.

I connect to the internet via my iPhone hotspot - no issues connecting via this to my MacBookPro or my iPad or anyne else who visits and wants to connectm can always do so. However, on my Macbook (yes, Macbook!!) on which I just installed dual boot Xubuntu, I am unable to see or connect to any WiFi point.

Can someone advise as to what i do next please?
Thanks

Added output of requested code, not sure how best to use the tags!

```
    enter code here 00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a00] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub [106b:00a1]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) [8086:2a02] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915, intelfb
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) [8086:2a03] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) [106b:00a1]
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2834] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2835] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:283a] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:284b] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:283f] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2847] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:2849] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2830] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2831] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2832] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:2836] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2815] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller [8086:2850] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2829] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [106b:00a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:283e] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller [106b:00a1]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0088]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:436a] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Imac 8,1 Wired Ethernet Adapter [11ab:00ba]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
    Kernel modules: sky2
04:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller [11c1:5811] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller [11c1:5811]
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/908379/edit) your question to include the output of `lspci -knn`.

Comment: Done... but made a mess of posting that info, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Apple Macbooks ship with broadcom wireless adapters, not typically shipped by default in Ubuntu distros

If you can tether the Macbook to your iPhone, you should be able to simply run

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and reboot.

Failing which, update your question with the result again; you can also see the lengthier suggestions in the [formal documentaion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)... good luck.

Comment: Loving the support here... thanks so much folks!  I have to start somewhere, and to get this support is awesome.  Thank you.